# Deployment a Qt Application on Mac

Tags: qt, deployment, qt4, imagemagick

I made an application and it seems its working fine when I build the release mode.
Here is the output of : otool -L RightDoneIt.app/Contents/MacOs/rightdoneit

```
/opt/local/lib/libMagick++.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.0)
QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 625.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1)
```

As you can see from the first line, Im using the ImageMagick library

After that, I to deploy with the macdeployqt tool : deployqt RightDoneIt.app -dmg 
That produces all the expected files and when I type check with otool Im getting

```
@executable_path/../Frameworks/libMagick++.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.0)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.7.0, current version 4.7.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 625.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1)
```

If I try to run the application made with the deploytool, I get a runtime error everytime Im trying to run an ImageMagick function.

Does anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: What's the error? doesn't libMagick++ depend on further libraries, like the libmagick C library/libraries? Check libMagick++.dylib with otool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the similar situation with, and cannot find an automatic tool on web. Just check libMagick++.4.dylib using otool, and run install_name_tool for libMagick++.4.dylib

Answer (score 1):

For Reference :

- [Mac Deployment](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/deployment-mac.html)
- Developing A QtCreator App for the Mac App Store

Here `xxxx` = application name

1. Build your Project in Release Mode shallow build.
2. `cd /Users/QtSDK/QtSources/4.7.4/bin`  or `/Users/xxxx/Desktop/abc/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4/bin`
3. In terminal:     `./macdeployqt "path to .app file"`
4. This will create app file with all dependent library then 
   In terminal:

   - `CD "Release folder (.app folder)"`
   - `install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/libtag.1.dylib xxxx.app/Contents/Frameworks/libtag.1.dylib`
   - `install_name_tool -change /Users/xxxx/wav/taglib-1.8/Build/taglib/libtag.1.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libtag.1.dylib xxxx.app/Contents/MacOs/xxxx`
   - `install_name_tool -change /Users/xxxx/wav/taglib-1.8/Build/taglib/libtag.1.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libtag.1.dylib xxxx.app/Contents/Frameworks/libtag.1.dylib`
5. Check other dependent libraries like taglib by terminal command
   `CD "Release folder`
    In terminal:   `tool -L appliaxtion` file if it any error then  `CD xxxx.app/Contents/MacOS` then type `tool -L xxxx` and see all dependent libraries
   and do step 4. for all dependent libraries.
6. Copy all dependent library to `app/contents/Frameworks`.
7. Copy `ffmpeg`, `lastfm` etc(only required folder or files)  to `app/contents/MacOs`
   For Making DMG:- ([details are here](http://blog.ivandemarino.me/2011/04/28/Need-to-ship-your-Qt-app-for-Mac-Bundle-it-up)) or Use DMG Canvas.